# Understanding rearrangement and simplification of products of adjacent transpositions.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Whilst working with permutations I have attempted to write several as products of disjoint cycles and adjacent transpositions. Below is an example:

$\sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\\ 
 2 & 3 & 7 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 9 & 8
\end{pmatrix}$

From here I constructed a product of disjoint cycles:

$\sigma =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$

Given that both

$\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}8 & 9\end{pmatrix}$

are both already adjacent transpositions, I simply sought to decompose

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

into adjacent transpositions as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4\end{pmatrix} =
 \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}2 & 3\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}3 & 7\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}7 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

From this, only two transpositions need to be made adjacent:

$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 7\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$

Finally I rewrote these transpositions as:

$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}$

respectively.

When reinstating these products of adjacent transpositions into the product of disjoint cycles one seems to get an incredibly cumbersome product:

$\sigma =\\\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}8 & 9\end{pmatrix}$

I understand that transpositions are their own inverses, however, I do not understand how to apply pairwise distinct commutativity or the Braid relation, or for that matter, what these really state, if either of those are applicable here. I have spent several hours conducting independent research and have found nothing I can use to simplify this expression. My research has included sources such as a variety of UK and USA university documentation and lectures, Stack Exchange, along with a myriad of other websites and documents.

This is my first post on here so I apologise if this question is too clunky or drawn out, I thought it best to include as much context as possible and fully detail what I have already done in case an error lies therein.

Any direction on how to rearrange and simplify expressions of adjacent transpositions would be massively appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you have done if the permutation were $(1 \ 3 \ 2)$ instead?

Comment: I'm presuming you're talking about the disjoint cycle being just (132) instead of (12374), in which case I would have rewritten as (12)(13)=(12)(12)(23)(12)=(23)(12)? @JBL

Comment: Following the procedure in the question, I was expecting you to write $(1 \ 3 \ 2) = (1 \ 3)(2 \ 3)$ and then expand $(1 \ 3) = (1 \ 2)(2 \ 3)(1 \ 2)$, so that the whole thing is $(1 \ 2)(2 \ 3)(1 \ 2)(2 \ 3)$.  Then what?

Comment: That's the thing, whilst I completely understand the different way to turn a permutation into a product of transpositions as you've highlighted here, with $(132) = (12)(23)(12)(23)$ I have no idea of any properties of transpositions that would enable a simplification of that expression.

Comment: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Generators_and_relations  (these relations are precisely the braid relations you mentioned).  The third relation is most useful in the form $\sigma_i \sigma_{i + 1} \sigma_i = \sigma_{i + 1} \sigma_i\sigma_{i + 1}$.

Comment: Great, thanks for the direction. Much appreciated. @JBL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This question duplicates with [I am trying to understand how to rearrange and simplify adjacent transpositions of permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4664274), and I decide to move my answer to here.)

---

It’s more likely to be a combinatorial problem.

Consider the [number of inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) of the sequence $(2, 3, 7, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8)$.
It’s $10$, and we can construct a sequence of operations to achieve this value by always swapping an adjacent inversion (proof of existence?). Example:
$$
(\underline{1, 2}, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) \\
(2, \underline{1, 3}, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 1, 4, 5, \underline{6, 7}, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 1, 4, \underline{5, 7}, 6, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 1, \underline{4, 7}, 5, 6, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, \underline{1, 7}, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, \underline{4, 5}, 6, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, 5, \underline{4, 6}, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, \underline{5, 6}, 4, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, 6, 5, 4, \underline{8, 9}) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8)
$$

Note that for a permutation $\sigma$, the right action of a transposition $(i\ \ (i+1))$, that is, $\sigma \circ (i\ \ (i+1))$, is to swap the $i$-th and the $(i+1)$-th number in the two-line notation. Therefore, we can recover the decomposition:
$$
\sigma = (1\ \ 2) (2\ \ 3) (6\ \ 7) (5\ \ 6) (4\ \ 5) (3\ \ 4) (5\ \ 6) (6\ \ 7) (5\ \ 6) (8\ \ 9) \text{.}
$$

(And of course it’s the shortest possible, as one swapping increases at most $1$ inversion.)

---

The cycle decomposition itself doesn’t tell the information about the number of inversions that much (maybe a lower bound and the parity), and so does transportations. I’m not sure whether it’s possible or not to simplify the product by looking at the local information about the product only. And I don’t think the braid group can help. Considering these, I think this combinatorial construction should be satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks great, just as a follow up, would the same method have worked if I simply applied it to the disjoint 5-cycle stated in the question? Say I were working with a permutation of a higher group, as such avoiding 12, 15 lines of working or more. @PinkRabbit

Comment: @Matt0121 I’m not pretty much sure about that. Just as I mentioned, I believed that by only looking at **one** cycle instead of **all** cycles decomposed cannot give full information. The exception is when each cycle forms a contiguous interval (elements in it are contiguous after sorting), in this case the cycles are not affecting others. Just like the cycle (8 9) in your case.