# I am trying to understand how to rearrange and simplify adjacent transpositions of permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Whilst working with permutations I have attempted to write several as products of disjoint cycles and adjacent transpositions. Below is an example:

$\sigma = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\\ 
 2 & 3 & 7 & 1 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 9 & 8
\end{pmatrix}$

From here I constructed a product of disjoint cycles:

$\sigma =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$

Given that both
$\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}$
and
$\begin{pmatrix}8 & 9\end{pmatrix}$
are both already adjacent transpositions, I simply sought to decompose
$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4\end{pmatrix}$
into adjacent transpositions as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 7 & 4\end{pmatrix} =
 \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}2 & 3\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}3 & 7\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}7 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

From this, only two transpositions need to be made adjacent:

$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 7\end{pmatrix}$
and
$\begin{pmatrix}4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$

Finally I rewrote these transpositions as:

$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}$

respectively.

When reinstating these products of adjacent transpositions into the product of disjoint cycles one seems to get an incredibly cumbersome product:

$\sigma =\\\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}6 & 7\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}4 & 5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}8 & 9\end{pmatrix}$

I understand that transpositions are their own inverses, however, I do not understand how to apply pairwise distinct commutativity or the Braid relation, if either of those are applicable here. I have spent several hours conducting independent research and have found nothing I can use to simplify this expression.

This is my first post on here so I apologise if this questions is too clunky or drawn out, I thought it best to include as much context as possible and fully detail what I have already done in case an error lies therein.

Any direction on how to rearrange and simplify expressions of adjacent transpositions would be massively appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem isn't that your question is clunky or drawn out, it's that it's off topic for this website. Mathoverflow is a place for professional mathematicians to ask each other questions about their research. Try asking on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Okay no worries, thanks for the heads, up, I'm new to all of this and I didn't realise there was a Stack Exchange explicitly for mathematics, I thought it was purely for programming and coding. @NikWeaver

Answer (score 1):

It’s more likely to be a combinatorial problem.

Consider the [number of inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) of the sequence $(2, 3, 7, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8)$.
It’s $10$, and we can construct a sequence of operations to achieve this value by always swapping an adjacent inversion (proof of existence?). Example:
$$
(\underline{1, 2}, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) \\
(2, \underline{1, 3}, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 1, 4, 5, \underline{6, 7}, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 1, 4, \underline{5, 7}, 6, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 1, \underline{4, 7}, 5, 6, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, \underline{1, 7}, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, \underline{4, 5}, 6, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, 5, \underline{4, 6}, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, \underline{5, 6}, 4, 8, 9) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, 6, 5, 4, \underline{8, 9}) \\
(2, 3, 7, 1, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8)
$$

Note that for a permutation $\sigma$, the right action of a transposition $(i\ \ (i+1))$, that is, $\sigma \circ (i\ \ (i+1))$, is to swap the $i$-th and the $(i+1)$-th number in the two-line notation. Therefore, we can recover the decomposition:
$$
\sigma = (1\ \ 2) (2\ \ 3) (6\ \ 7) (5\ \ 6) (4\ \ 5) (3\ \ 4) (5\ \ 6) (6\ \ 7) (5\ \ 6) (8\ \ 9) \text{.}
$$

(And of course it’s the shortest possible, as one swapping increases at most $1$ inversion.)